# Cosmos DB Query Projection

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have Cosmos Document of below format:

(**Note**: Example is just for illustration, the actual document has different properties)

```
{
        "OrderNumer":"12345",
        "Version":"5",
        "OrderDetails": [ 
            {
                "id":1,
                "OrderItem": {
                    "Name": "ABC",
                    "Description": "ABC Description",
                     .
                     .
                     .
                },
                "PaymentDetails": {
                },
                .
                .
                .
            },
            {
                "id":2,
                "OrderItem": {
                    "Name": "PQR",
                    "Description": "PQR Description",
                     .
                     .
                     .
                },
                "PaymentDetails": {
                },
                .
                .
                .
            },
        ],
        "OrderDate": "12-01-2020",
        "CustomerDetails": {
         }
        .
        .
        .
}
```

`OrderNumber` is a partition key.

I'm trying to project the above document through Cosmos Query to get the entire `OrderDetails` JSON object and a few properties from the parent into a single JSON with a filter on `OrderDetails`-> `id`.

The expected projection should be:

```
{
    "Order":
    [
        {
           "OrderNumer":"12345",
            "Version":"5",
            "id":1,
            "OrderItem": {
                "Name": "ABC",
                "Description": "ABC Description",
                 .
                 .
                 .
            },

            "PaymentDetails": {
            },
            .
            .
            .
        },
        {
            "OrderNumer":"12345",
            "Version":"5",
            "id":2,
            "OrderItem": {
                "Name": "PQR",
                "Description": "PQR Description",
                 .
                 .
                 .
            },
            "PaymentDetails": {
            },
            .
            .
            .
        },
    ]
}
```

As shown in the above JSON, I'm projecting `OrderNumber` and `Version` properties within the `OrderDetails` as `Order`.

`OrderDetails` is a massive JSON with a dynamic schema that makes it difficult for us to project its properties individually.

I have tried a few options to project this, but the closest I could reach was below query:

```
SELECT c.OrderNumber, c.Version, o as Order
FROM c
JOIN o in c.OrderDetails WHERE
c.OrderNumber= '1235' AND ARRAY_CONTAINS([1,2], o.id)
```

However, the above query does not give desired result as it keeps the `OrderNumber` and `Version` in as separate property to `Order`.

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: Please edit your question and include the query that you have written so far and tell us the issues you're running into.

Comment: try this sql :  `SELECT c.OrderNumer,c.Version,o.OrderItem,o.PaymentDetails FROM c join o in c.OrderDetails`   then  `new JsonObject ` add this result via code.

Comment: Have you tried the query posted by @SteveZhao? Did that work?

Comment: The query misses one of my requirements,  I need all the properties from `OrderDetails` and `OrderDetails` has a huge and dynamic dataset. So I prefer to select it in entirety. Hope this clarifies

Answer (score 2):

You can use UDF.

First:create a udf,below is code

```
function Converted(version,orderNumber,orderItem){
    orderItem.Version = version;
    orderItem.OrderNumber = orderNumber;
    return orderItem;
}
```

Second:use this sql

```
select value udf.Converted(c.Version,c.OrderNumber,o) from c join o in c.OrderDetails WHERE c.OrderNumber= '12345' AND ARRAY_CONTAINS([1,2], o.id)
```

Finally:new JsonObject  add this result via code.

Here is result:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "OrderItem": {
            "Name": "ABC",
            "Description": "ABC Description"
        },
        "PaymentDetails": {},
        "Version": "5",
        "OrderNumber": "12345"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "OrderItem": {
            "Name": "PQR",
            "Description": "PQR Description"
        },
        "PaymentDetails": {},
        "Version": "5",
        "OrderNumber": "12345"
    }
]
```

Does this meet your requirements?

Comment: That's a great, idea. Thanks for the suggestion.  I guess the one issue with this approach is that we would need to create a separate `udf` in Javascript. The function needs to be executed/ deployed in a different way from the rest of the code. We use C# Cosmos SDK to perform all our operations on the Cosmos Document. We try to avoid the stored procedures, triggers, UDF as much as possible. This, now, would be an exception.

Do you think that is the only way? If that is the case, I'm leaning more towards creating a separate POCO document to deserialize it (instead of creating a UDF).

Comment: I"m glad to hear that this is helpful to you.As far as I am aware,this is the only way to do this.I have tried many sql,but they don't work.

Answer (score -1):

I know this is too late to answer, till now you have resolved your problem but still providing the query to help other people who may have faced a similar issue.

CosmosDB provides flexibility which will help you to modify output JSON structure. Please see the below query for above problem.

Query:

```
SELECT  
 [
     {
        "OrderNumer": c.OrderNumer,
        "Version": c.Version,
        "id": od.id,
        "OrderItem": {
            "Name": od.OrderItem.Name,
            "Description": od.OrderItem.Description
        }
     }
 ] AS Orders
 FROM c
 JOIN od IN c.OrderDetails
```

Happy coding!

Comment: Don't think it answers my question.